# Configuration for Kubernetes Flask and Prometheus

Tags: python, kubernetes, flask, prometheus

I am trying to configure a prometheus to monitor a simple flask app, but its very weird that the prometheus does show the service in the drop down, but it shows nothing when I click in the dropdown:

[image: blank]

Here is the code:

app.py

```
from flask import Flask
from prometheus_flask_exporter import PrometheusMetrics

app = Flask(__name__)
metrics = PrometheusMetrics(app)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5000)
```

flask-deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: flask-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: flask-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: flask-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: flask-app
        image: starian/flask-app1
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5000
          name: webapp
```

flask-service.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: flask-app-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: flask-app
  ports:
    - name: http
      protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: webapp
  type: LoadBalancer
```

service-monitor.yaml

```
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: ServiceMonitor
metadata:
  name: flask-app
  labels:
    release: prometheus-stack
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: flask-app
  endpoints:
  - port: http
    interval: 5s
    path: /metrics
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8-slim

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app

RUN pip install flask
RUN pip install prometheus_flask_exporter

CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

I check everything that I know of:
THe metrics does show in the the flask app. I can curl it.
All the services is on.

What could goes wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`servicemonitor` object looks for services with the label selectors that you give in the manifest , the name of the object is telling you exactly what it does. it looks for a `service` with the `app: flask-app` label not the **pod**.
so if you look at your service manifest it does not have **lables** so the service monitor is monitoring nothing , if you create another service monitor with another labelselector it is shown just like that in prometheus targets.
to sum it up , edit your service manifest:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: flask-app-service
  labels:
    app: flask-app
spec:
  selector:
    app: flask-app
  ports:
    - name: http
      protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: webapp
  type: LoadBalancer
```

Hope that helps! :)

Comment: That's PINPOINT the problem! Thank you very much.